# have_posts() срабатывает со 2 раза

Tags: wordpress

Стандартный код wordpress, код контента страницы page.php.
Постоянные ссылки: `/%post_type%/%postname%/`
При замене на "Простые" или любой другой тип ссылок ничего не меняется, htaccess стандартный.
Проблема такого характера: если открыть страницу с ниже указанным кодом, то выдаст "Nothing Found", а если раскомментировать первый `have_posts();` , то содержимое отображается. И так со всеми страницами и записями, кроме главной страницы. Получается, что have_posts срабатывает как положено со 2 раза (хотя содержимое контента имеется). Из-за чего это может быть и как это исправить? Может кто сталкивался?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php //have_posts(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'page'); ?>

    <?php if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) : ?>
      <?php comments_template(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Скорее всего, дело в том, что уже где то запущен цикл и в конце его не сделан rewind_posts(). В этом случае такое поведение понятно. Первый have_posts() вызывает rewind_posts, после чего цикл снова становится доступен.

Comment: Вы правы, благодарю за помощь!